# What is the direction of $dl$ vector in Ampere's Law?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If you take an amperian loop then, how do we find the direction of dl vector at different points on the loop?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is in a little more detail?

Comment: Actually, the direction is oftenly of current in this case.

Answer (score 1):

if you consider a point on the loop then the tangent of the loop at that point represents the direction of $dl$ vector

Answer (score 0):

The direction of $dl$ vector can be found by drawing tangent to the loop at each point.